# Capture tick of setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Is there any possibilities of capturing tick of each seconds in `setTimeout`. Say for a scenario I need to logout user after 5 seconds with a message displayed, say in a `div`, saying "You will be logged out in 5 seconds". then 4,3,2,1 and logout after `timeOut`

Ex:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $("#myDiv").text("you will be logged out in " + n + " seconds");
     //"n" being tick of each second.
},5000)
```

I searched over internet for this but nowhere I can see the solution. Or anything that can be done with `setInterval` for this scenario is also good point here. Any ideas or light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could use the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) in conjunction with the [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) methods:

```
var n = 5;
var timeoutID = window.setInterval(function() {
    // this callback will execute every second until we call
    // the clearInterval method
    $('#myDiv').text('you will be logged out in ' + n + ' seconds');
    n--;
    if (n === 0) {
        // TODO: go ahead and really log the dude out

        window.clearInterval(timeoutID);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a global variable and use that to show tick. like below

```
var counter = 5;
var timeInterval= setTimeout(function(){
  $("#myDiv").text("you will be logged out in " + n + " seconds");
   //"n" being tick of each second.
   counter = counter - 1;
   clearInterval(timeInterval) if(counter==0)
},1000)
```

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao please accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: Your answer has a syntax error. JavaScript doesn't have postscript conditionals (like, e.g., PERL).